# An $\omega$-stable theory that is not uncountably categorical

Tags: logic, model-theory, equivalence-relations

Morley's theorem states that a countable complete theory that's $\omega$-stable and has no Vaughtian pair is uncountably categorical. From the statement, I guess the "no Vaughtian pair" condition is necessary. In searching for examples of theories that are $\omega$-stable (with Vaughtian pair) but not uncountably categorical, I stumbled upon this [article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235420894). An example is given in Example 3.1.3, namely the theory in the language $\{E\}$ saying that $E$ is an equivalence relation and that for each natural number $n$, there is one $E$-class of size $n$. However, I don't understand the argument in the article, so I might just ask for an explanation here.

Why is this theory $\omega$-stable but not uncountably categorical?

Comment: In addition to proving that this theory is $\omega$-stable and not uncountably categorical, it's also worth proving that this theory is complete (usually completeness is part of the definition of $\omega$-stability). Proving completeness is actually a bit trickier than the other two parts, in my opinion. You can do it with an EF game or by adding a unary relation symbol $P_n$ to the language to name the equivalence class of size $n$ and then proving quantifier elimination in the expanded language.

Comment: By the way, there are many other examples of $\omega$-stable but not uncountably categorical theories. For example: (1) the theory of a single unary relation symbol picking out an infinite and coinfinite set (2) the theory of an equivalence relation with infinitely many infinite classes (3) the theory of a complete infinitely branching tree in the language of graphs (4) the theory $DCF_0$ of differentially closed fields of characteristic $0$.

Comment: Note that $(2)$ of Alex's comment is really a simplified version of what's going on in my answer. Meanwhile, $(4)$ is great because it's a *natural* example, even to non-logicians, of an $\omega$-stable non-uncountably-categorical theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this theory "$T$."

---

Showing that $T$ is not uncountably categorical is straightforward. Keep in mind that a model of $T$ is gotten by adjoining to the prime model (= one equivalence class of size $n$ for each finite $n$) an arbitrary number (possibly $0$) of equivalence classes of arbitrary infinite cardinalities. Now given $\kappa$ infinite, the following are some examples of non-isomorphic models of $T$ with cardinality $\kappa$:

- Exactly one class of size $\kappa$, no other infinite classes.
- Exactly two classes of size $\kappa$, no other infinite classes.
- For $\kappa>\aleph_0$: exactly one class of size $\kappa$, exactly one class of size $\aleph_0$, no other infinite classes.

And so on. Personally I think the last example is especially important; it's good to keep in mind that similar-looking "pieces" of the model (e.g. infinite classes) can behave very differently.

---

As for $\omega$-stability, let's start by considering the no-parameters case: can we show that there are only countably many $1$-types over $\emptyset$?

(As usual we're working in some "sufficiently saturated" monster model $\mathfrak{M}$ here.)

Well, intuitively the $1$-type over $\emptyset$ of some element $a$ is determined by a simple cardinal invariant $size(a)$:

> Take $size(a)$ to be the size of the equivalence class $a$ lives in.

After proving that in fact $size(a)=size(b)$ implies $tp_\emptyset(a)=tp_\emptyset(b)$, we can now count the number of possible values of this invariant within the monster model $\mathfrak{M}$:

> Either $size(a)$ is finite, or by saturation $size(a)=\vert\mathfrak{M}\vert$. So there are $\aleph_0$-many possible values of $size(a)$.

We now need to think about folding in parameter sets larger than $\emptyset$ and tuple lengths larger than $1$ - that is, counting $n$-types over $A$ for arbitrary finite $n$ and countable $A\subseteq\mathfrak{M}$. **EDIT: not really, see Alex Kruckman's comment below; I'm making things harder than they need to be here.** This gets a bit tedious, but the basic idea is still the same: we want to show that there are only a few different possible behaviors for a given tuple.

For example, here's how to count the $2$-types over a one-element parameter set $\{c\}$. The type of a pair $(a_0,a_1)$ in $\mathfrak{M}$ over $\{c\}$ is determined by the following data.

First, we have the "$\emptyset$-part" of each individual element of the pair $(a_0,a_1)$:

> What are the cardinalities $\alpha_0$, $\alpha_1$ of the classes of $a_0,a_1$ in $\mathfrak{M}$? As before, there are $\aleph_0$-many possibilities here.

Next, we consider the structure *within* the tuple $(a_0,a_1)$:

> Are $a_0$ and $a_1$ equal? Are $a_0$ and $a_1$ equivalent? There are finitely many possibilities here.

Finally, we bring the parameter into the question:

> How do $a_0$ and $a_1$ compare with $c$, both with respect to *equality* and *equivalence*? Again, there are only finitely many possible behaviors.

Putting all this together we get as hoped for only countably many $2$-types over a one-element parameter set in $\mathfrak{M}$. And it should be reasonably clear how to continue this to get $\omega$-stability.

Comment: +1, but to prove $\omega$-stability, you fortunately only need to count $1$-types (since an $n$-type over a countable set is determined by a sequence of $n$ $1$-types over countable sets). In this case, I think it's actually pretty straightforward to directly count the number of $1$-types over an arbitrary countably infinite set.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Good point, I forgot that it's enough to just count the $1$-types here (early in the morning still).

Comment: You can also assume the countable set of parameters is a model if you want. This makes it easier because every type which "lives in" a finite class is actually isolated by $x=a$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman can you maybe say a little bit more why it suffices to count 1-types?

Comment: @ikrto What is your definition of $\omega$-stable?

Comment: @ikrto Do you see for example why the $2$-type $tp(a,b/A)$ is determined by the $1$-types $tp(a/A)$ and $tp(b/Aa)$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman the definition I'm using is: $T$ is $\omega$-stable iff for any model $M\vDash T$ and countable $A\subseteq M$, the set of $n$-types over $A$ in M is countable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber is the idea like this: if $M\vDash \varphi(a,b)$ (with parameters from $A$), then $\exists y \varphi(x,y)$ is in $tp(a/A)$, and $\varphi(a,b)$ is in $tp(b/Aa)$?